# Concatenate variables in Dockerfile at runtime

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to concatenate JSON environment variable out of multiple parameters provided during runtime.

Simplified Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04                            
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS='{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"'${AZP_ENDPOINT}'", "username":"someuser", "password":"'${AZP_TOKEN}'"}]}'
```

Then i build image like this:

> docker build -t myubuntu .

and run it

> docker run -it -e AZP_ENDPOINT="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/nuget/v3/index.json" -e AZP_TOKEN="some token" myubuntu

However when i run **env** command inside the container i see the following picture. Variable provided during container run are there, but VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS has not been updated:

```
AZP_ENDPOINT=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/nuget/v3/index.json
AZP_TOKEN=some token
VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS={"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"", "username":"someuser", "password":""}]}
```

Just wondering what i'm doing wrong here?